# Jquery autocomplete post request only once

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete. I am not happy with the code below because there must be a better way to do this. (code works)

1. I want the user to enter 3 letters into the search box
2. autocomplete post parameters and server responds
3. **After we have the data coming from server there is no reason to post again.**
   note: autocomplete will keep on postind data every time user adds a new letter
4. since I have the data, I want to use this data as source of autocomplete

The code below works with a little problem. on select one it is display in the box. When I use **backspace it doesnt refresh/populate the suggestions**.

**Question**:
How can I use autocomplete to post only once and reuse the response adn the source for the autocomplete?

If can anyone suggest or point any document I could read.

Thanks

```
jquery-1.9.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.10.0/jquery-ui.js

     $("#birds").autocomplete
    ({
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax(
    {
    url: "page.aspx",
    data: {
    Para: request.term,
    GroupID: 11,
    rGUI: 'd9',
    rURL: 'domain.com/',
    task: 'get Stuff'
    },
    type: "POST",  
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function(data) {

    //response: function(item) {
    var arr = $.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
    label: item.LN60,
    value: item.LN60,
    NDC: item.NDC
    }
    });

    $("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: arr,
    minLength: 1
    });

    $("#birds").autocomplete({
    close: function(event, ui) {
    suggestDrugs_Request();
    }
    });

    }
    });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + 
    " aka " + ui.item.NDC : "Nothing selected, input was "
     + this.value);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Use a cache... http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache . Also in terms of backspacing, are the characters under the minLength?

Comment: The problem with caching, is that he's getting the data asynchronously. the cache won't exist when he binds the autocomplete.

Comment: jquery cache keeps on calling the server every time user enter a new letter into the input box

Answer (score 4):

What you should do instead of adding the ajax call to the source property of the autocomplete, is add the autocomplete functioniality to the callback of the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
//all your other call settings
 success: function(data){
  //init autocomplete
  $('#birds').autocomplete({
       source: data,
       //all your other autocomplete settings
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: I know it can work... I've used this method hundreds of times. :)  good luck!

Comment: Brian, By doing what you have suggested then: I have to manually test when I need to make the call? I was wondering if there was a way to bind the autocomplete and handle all inside that routine. If not your suggestion makes sense and I will test it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  This function would fire once when the page loads, getting the source data for autocomplete, then binding it to the #birds element when the data is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Make the $.ajax request and bind your autocompletes (make the .autocomplete functioncalls) inside of the `success: function(data) {` function.

Then set the autocompletes' `source`s to the `data` that was returned (which is obviously static now)

Comment: Thanks Micah. This is close to what Brian suggested