# Javascript Autocomplete using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, autocomplete

Trying to get the autocomplete form working for materialize css using JQuery, but a couple issues autocomplete documentation shows that I should use 'data' and provide a JSON array for the autocomplete fields, but JQuery requires a 'source' function to even function. So I have to use 'source' field, and I provide it with an array of entries that has about 150 strings.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    var poke = "${pokemon}";
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data){
            $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
                source: poke,
                limit: 20
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The autocomplete dropdown never shows up, and there is no error in either the console or server.

I wanted to do it without the Ajax call, and just the autocomplete function, but I couldn't get it to just use the provided array of entries and instead it always tried a GET request on the array of entries, resulting in a "Request too large" error.

It doesn't have to be using Ajax but I just can't get the autocomplete to work regardless.

Comment: do you have a url for this ajax? what script does it load on the server?

Comment: @levi I was basing the ajax call on this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/15029052/7623100

The array of strings that I want to load into the autocomplete is already on the client but I couldn't get it to work when not using an ajax call due to the request header being too large, so I tried the ajax method in that post which didn't produce the error anymore, but it doesn't result in any error while still not making the autocomplete input work.